# Yeoman.io problems installing generator-angular

Tags: javascript, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

When writing question used the Google translator.
On a freshly installed ubuntu 14.04 set nodejs -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make nodejs
```

Then install yo -

```
sudo npm i -g yo
```

I then install [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) -

```
sudo npm i -g generator-angular
```

From the directory you open a terminal and install generator-angular -

```
yo angular
```

And get a lot of errors. Why? How to fix it?

Sergio Lopez Mendez - Thank You for your help!
Я изменил прова на директорию `node_modules`

```
sudo chown -R user:group /usr/lib/node_modules/
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

And mistakes are almost gone, but still, almost..

```
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No README data
deprecated grunt-ngmin@0.0.3: use grunt-ng-annotate instead
```

...

```
npm WARN deprecated ngmin@0.4.1: use ng-annotate instead
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.2.0
```

...

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.9.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/grunt-legacy-log requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.9.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob requires minimatch@'0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/minimatch,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.2.14
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse requires underscore.string@'~2.3.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/underscore.string,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn/node_modules/bower requires semver@'~2.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn/node_modules/semver,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.1
WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress requires mkdirp@'^0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-jpegtran/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress requires mkdirp@'^0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress requires mkdirp@'^0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
 which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data requires async@'~0.9.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress requires mkdirp@'^0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
```

And just in case all of the text

```
acopalipsis@acopalipsis-pc:~$ cd /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/
acopalipsis@acopalipsis-pc:~/my-test-two$ yo angular

     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\    
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

Out of the box I include Bootstrap and some AngularJS recommended modules.

[?] Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? No
[?] Would you like to include Bootstrap? Yes
[?] Which modules would you like to include? angular-animate.js, angular-cookies.js, angular-resource.js, angular-route.js, angular-sanitize.js, angular-touch.js
   create app/styles/main.css
   create app/index.html
   create bower.json
identical .bowerrc
   create package.json
   create Gruntfile.js
   invoke   angular:common:/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
identical     .editorconfig
identical     .gitattributes
identical     .jshintrc
identical     .gitignore
   create     test/.jshintrc
   create     app/.buildignore
   create     app/.htaccess
   create     app/404.html
   create     app/favicon.ico
   create     app/robots.txt
   create     app/views/main.html
   create     app/images/yeoman.png
   invoke   angular:main:/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
   create     app/scripts/app.js
   invoke   angular:controller:/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
   create     app/scripts/controllers/main.js
   create     test/spec/controllers/main.js
   invoke   karma:app


I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


   invoke       angular:route
   invoke           angular:controller:/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
   create             app/scripts/controllers/about.js
   create             test/spec/controllers/about.js
   invoke           angular:view:/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
   create             app/views/about.html
   create     test/karma.conf.js
identical     .travis.yml
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mytesttwo@0.0.0 No README data
deprecated grunt-ngmin@0.0.3: use grunt-ng-annotate instead
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#3.3.2
bower validate      3.3.2 against git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.3.1
bower cached        git://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#3.1.1
bower validate      3.1.1 against git://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#~3.1.0
bower cached        git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.2.0
bower validate      3.2.0 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.2.0
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.16
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.16
bower validate      1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.16
npm WARN deprecated ngmin@0.4.1: use ng-annotate instead
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.2.0
bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.1
bower validate      2.1.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.9.0
bower install       json3#3.3.2
bower install       es5-shim#3.1.1
bower install       angular-resource#1.2.16
bower install       bootstrap#3.2.0
bower install       angular-mocks#1.2.16
bower install       angular-scenario#1.2.16
bower install       angular-sanitize#1.2.16
bower install       angular#1.2.16
bower install       angular-route#1.2.16
bower install       angular-animate#1.2.16
bower install       angular-touch#1.2.16
bower install       angular-cookies#1.2.16
bower install       jquery#2.1.1

> phantomjs@1.9.7-14 install /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
-
json3#3.3.2 bower_components/json3

es5-shim#3.1.1 bower_components/es5-shim

angular-resource#1.2.16 bower_components/angular-resource
└── angular#1.2.16

bootstrap#3.2.0 bower_components/bootstrap
└── jquery#2.1.1

angular-mocks#1.2.16 bower_components/angular-mocks
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-scenario#1.2.16 bower_components/angular-scenario
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-sanitize#1.2.16 bower_components/angular-sanitize
└── angular#1.2.16

angular#1.2.16 bower_components/angular

angular-route#1.2.16 bower_components/angular-route
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-animate#1.2.16 bower_components/angular-animate
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-touch#1.2.16 bower_components/angular-touch
└── angular#1.2.16

angular-cookies#1.2.16 bower_components/angular-cookies
└── angular#1.2.16

jquery#2.1.1 bower_components/jquery
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1405706835721/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64 -> /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

> ws@0.4.31 install /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Вход в каталог `/home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Выход из каталога `/home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.9.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/grunt-legacy-log requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.9.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob requires minimatch@'0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/minimatch,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.2.14
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/argparse requires underscore.string@'~2.3.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/underscore.string,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn/node_modules/bower requires semver@'~2.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn/node_modules/semver,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.1
WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress requires mkdirp@'^0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-jpegtran/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress requires mkdirp@'^0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress requires mkdirp@'^0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
 which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data requires async@'~0.9.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/decompress requires mkdirp@'^0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
grunt-karma@0.8.3 node_modules/grunt-karma
└── lodash@2.4.1

karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
└── phantomjs@1.9.7-14 (which@1.0.5, progress@1.1.7, rimraf@2.2.8, ncp@0.4.2, kew@0.1.7, mkdirp@0.3.5, request-progress@0.3.1, adm-zip@0.2.1, npmconf@0.0.24, request@2.36.0)

karma@0.12.17 node_modules/karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── chokidar@0.8.2 (recursive-readdir@0.0.2)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── source-map@0.1.37 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── useragent@2.0.9 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── connect@2.12.0 (uid2@0.0.3, methods@0.1.0, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.1, debug@0.8.1, fresh@0.2.0, qs@0.6.6, bytes@0.2.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, raw-body@1.1.2, batch@0.5.0, cookie@0.1.0, negotiator@0.3.0, send@0.1.4, multiparty@2.2.0)
├── socket.io@0.9.17 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
├── log4js@0.6.16 (semver@1.1.4, readable-stream@1.0.27-1, async@0.1.15)
└── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)

karma-jasmine@0.1.5 node_modules/karma-jasmine

> pngquant-bin@0.3.1 postinstall /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node index.js

✓ pre-build test passed successfully

> jpegtran-bin@0.2.7 postinstall /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-jpegtran/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node index.js

✓ pre-build test passed successfully

> gifsicle@0.1.6 postinstall /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle
> node index.js

✓ pre-build test passed successfully

> optipng-bin@0.3.9 postinstall /home/acopalipsis/my-test-two/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node index.js

✓ pre-build test passed successfully
grunt-contrib-copy@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy

jshint-stylish@0.2.0 node_modules/jshint-stylish
├── text-table@0.2.0
└── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

grunt-concurrent@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-concurrent
├── pad-stdio@0.1.1 (lpad@0.2.1)
└── async@0.2.10

grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean
└── rimraf@2.2.8

grunt-contrib-concat@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat
└── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

time-grunt@0.3.2 node_modules/time-grunt
├── date-time@0.1.1
├── pretty-ms@0.1.0
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── text-table@0.2.0
└── chalk@0.4.0 (ansi-styles@1.0.0, has-color@0.1.7, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

grunt-filerev@0.2.1 node_modules/grunt-filerev
├── each-async@0.1.3
└── chalk@0.4.0 (ansi-styles@1.0.0, has-color@0.1.7, strip-ansi@0.1.1)

grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.9.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── clean-css@2.1.8 (commander@2.1.0)
└── maxmin@0.1.0 (pretty-bytes@0.1.1, gzip-size@0.1.1)

grunt-newer@0.7.0 node_modules/grunt-newer
├── rimraf@2.2.6
└── async@0.2.10

grunt-contrib-uglify@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── maxmin@0.1.0 (pretty-bytes@0.1.1, gzip-size@0.1.1)
└── uglify-js@2.4.15 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, optimist@0.3.7, source-map@0.1.34)

grunt-ngmin@0.0.3 node_modules/grunt-ngmin
└── ngmin@0.4.1 (astral@0.1.0, clone@0.1.17, commander@1.1.1, astral-angular-annotate@0.0.2, escodegen@0.0.28, esprima@1.0.4)

grunt-contrib-htmlmin@0.3.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin
├── pretty-bytes@0.1.1
├── chalk@0.4.0 (ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1, has-color@0.1.7)
└── html-minifier@0.6.5 (change-case@2.1.1, clean-css@2.2.8, cli@0.6.3, uglify-js@2.4.15)

grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint
├── hooker@0.2.3
└── jshint@2.5.2 (strip-json-comments@0.1.3, underscore@1.6.0, exit@0.1.2, console-browserify@1.1.0, minimatch@0.4.0, shelljs@0.3.0, cli@0.6.3, htmlparser2@3.7.3)

grunt-wiredep@1.8.0 node_modules/grunt-wiredep
└── wiredep@1.8.2 (modmod@0.1.2, propprop@0.3.0, minimist@0.1.0, chalk@0.1.1, through2@0.4.2, glob@3.2.11, lodash@1.3.1, bower-config@0.5.2)

grunt-autoprefixer@0.7.6 node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer
├── diff@1.0.8
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── autoprefixer@1.3.1 (fs-extra@0.9.1, postcss@0.3.5, caniuse-db@1.0.20140717)

grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch
├── async@0.2.10
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3, qs@0.5.6)
├── gaze@0.5.1 (globule@0.1.0)
└── lodash@2.4.1

grunt-usemin@2.3.0 node_modules/grunt-usemin
├── debug@1.0.4 (ms@0.6.2)
└── lodash@2.4.1

grunt-contrib-connect@0.7.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect
├── connect-livereload@0.3.2
├── open@0.0.4
├── portscanner@0.2.2 (async@0.1.15)
├── async@0.2.10
└── connect@2.13.1 (uid2@0.0.3, methods@0.1.0, debug@0.8.1, cookie-signature@1.0.1, pause@0.0.1, fresh@0.2.0, qs@0.6.6, bytes@0.2.1, raw-body@1.1.3, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, batch@0.5.0, cookie@0.1.0, compressible@1.0.0, negotiator@0.3.0, send@0.1.4, multiparty@2.2.0)

load-grunt-tasks@0.4.0 node_modules/load-grunt-tasks
├── multimatch@0.1.0 (minimatch@0.2.14, lodash@2.4.1)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.1)

grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── which@1.0.5
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── exit@0.1.2
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.1)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.1)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.15)

grunt-svgmin@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-svgmin
├── pretty-bytes@0.1.1
├── each-async@0.1.3
├── chalk@0.4.0 (ansi-styles@1.0.0, has-color@0.1.7, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── svgo@0.4.4 (colors@0.6.2, whet.extend@0.9.9, coa@0.4.1, sax@0.6.0, js-yaml@2.1.3)

grunt-google-cdn@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-google-cdn
├── bower@1.3.8 (is-root@0.1.0, junk@0.3.0, stringify-object@0.2.1, abbrev@1.0.5, chmodr@0.1.0, which@1.0.5, osenv@0.1.0, opn@0.1.2, archy@0.0.2, lockfile@0.4.2, graceful-fs@3.0.2, rimraf@2.2.8, bower-logger@0.2.2, lru-cache@2.5.0, bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2, nopt@3.0.1, retry@0.6.1, chalk@0.4.0, tmp@0.0.23, request-progress@0.3.1, q@1.0.1, shell-quote@1.4.1, promptly@0.2.0, bower-json@0.4.0, mkdirp@0.5.0, p-throttler@0.0.1, fstream-ignore@0.0.10, semver@2.3.1, glob@4.0.4, bower-config@0.5.2, fstream@0.1.28, decompress-zip@0.0.8, tar@0.1.20, cardinal@0.4.4, request@2.36.0, handlebars@1.3.0, mout@0.9.1, bower-registry-client@0.2.1, insight@0.3.1, inquirer@0.5.1, update-notifier@0.2.0)
└── google-cdn@0.4.0 (regexp-quote@0.0.0, debug@0.7.4, google-cdn-data@0.1.5, async@0.2.10, semver@2.2.1, cdnjs-cdn-data@0.1.1, bower@1.2.8)

grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.7.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin
├── pretty-bytes@0.1.1
├── async@0.7.0
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── imagemin@0.4.6 (get-stdin@0.1.0, stat-mode@0.2.0, ware@0.2.1, image-type@0.1.4, rimraf@2.2.8, nopt@2.2.1, tempfile@0.1.3, fs-extra@0.8.1, imagemin-svgo@0.1.0, imagemin-pngquant@0.1.2, imagemin-jpegtran@0.1.0, imagemin-gifsicle@0.1.1, imagemin-optipng@0.1.0)
app/index.html modified.
```

Comment: Can you run `yo doctor` and paste the result into your answer?

Comment: @ Sergio Lopez Mendez:,Tell me how to run it?

Comment: Just paste the command `yo doctor` into a command line. Just like you did with `yo angular`

Comment: Finished at the end of the matter, however addition merged with the question. See the last two lines.

Comment: Then this is a problem with permissions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/24404451#24404451

Comment: @Sergio Lopez Mendez: Thank you! I added a question, you may be able to help...:)

Comment: If you're referring to the `npm WARN unmet dependency` lines you can safely ignore them. Try running `grunt serve`. If something's wrong it will let you now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with permissions. Either run

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

(from [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo))

or install node the right way as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404451/2079602

As for the second question, you can safely ignore any lines with:

`npm WARN unmet dependency`

Comment: @tTac I'm moving the fix from the comments to an answer

Comment: Thank You very much! Without You I would have failed!

Comment: What would a windows user do?

Comment: Similar pblm while installing gulp, unmet dependecy : glob requires   minimatch @2.0.1 but will load in windows. Thanks in advance

Comment: I followed those directions to install node the right way, but i'm still hitting this error. not as much as i was before i followed those directions, though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning and installing last nodejs version helped to solve it. You can do it next way:

```
nvm install v0.12.0 &&
nvm use v0.12.0 &&
npm install -g yo
```

Comment: Can you document more about how this solves the issue?